# Spring MVC/REST retrieving data only from certain domain

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I have a question regarding Spring MVC/Rest.

Say I have a service in which you can retrieve the user details (JSON) of a user by entering the following url `http://localhost:8080/project/api/get/user/1`.

My front-end application runs on: `http://localhost:9000/` and I am able to fetch the data from the API. However, I can do this on any domain. And my goal is to only serve a single (or list of) domains/ips.

So I added the following filter to my API for it to only accept calls from localhost:9000

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:9000");
      /* other code*/
```

Now it indeed blocks calls from other domains. However, if I use a tool like Postman, I am able to still fetch the data! Am I missing something? Is it a safe and correct way what I'm doing here? Why am I still able to fetch and even post data if I use Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS affects only requests between two different domains using AJAX

If you want only affect some of your controllers you can annote them like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')")
@Controller
public class Controller {

...

}
```

Else if you want to restrict all requests you can customize your filter

```
@Component
public class ValidDomainFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr();
        int port = req.getRemotePort();

        if(isValidDomain(ipAddress,port)){
            filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp").forward(req,res);
          /* redirect or do whatever you need*/
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidDomain(String ipAddress, int port){
    /* do validation */
    }

}
```